# Replace n-th element in CSV string

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I try to replace the n-th element of a CSV string, without knowing his value. For example, here is my string :

```
*;*;*;element_to_replace;*;*
```

With * an undefined string, it can be anything.

So i tried to use :

```
for /F "delims=" %%w in (file\workstation) do (
    set line=%%w
    if !compt! NEQ 0 (
        set new_line=!line:*;*;*;*=*;*;*;new_value!
        @echo !new_line! >> file\tmp_workstation
    ) else (
        @echo !header_workstation! >> file\tmp_workstation
    )
    set /A "compt+=1"
)
```

It doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: yes: you can't use wildcards here.

Comment: Wildcards are not supported ? But this documentation (http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is giving an example of wildcard : SET _result=%_test:*ab=XY%

Comment: that's a single wildcard, not (plural) wildcards. Note this is the only place, where it works. For exapmple `set _result)%_test:ab*=XY% does *not* work.

Comment: But that's the only allowed wildcard. Take all from the beginning including `<search>` and replace it with `<replace>` . Syntax `%variable:*<search>=<replace>%`

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "wildcard" for this substring substitution syntax in order not to be confused with `*` and `?` in path specifications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM you want to replace token 4:
for /f "tokens=1-4,* delims=;" %%a in (t.csv) do (
   echo %%a;%%b;%%c;replaced;%%e
)
```

`tokens=1-4,*` means: take the first four tokens, the fifth token is "the rest of the line". `%%a` is the first token, `%%b` is the second one etc.
You want to write `token1;token2;token3,"replacement string for the fourth token(%%d)";"rest of the line" (fifth token)`.

Comment: This is too simple, it fails with empty entries like `Name;;Phone;bla`. You need two FOR /F loops

Comment: Vincent: as @jeb noted: it works, as long as you don't have any "empty cells" (within the first four colums)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the `*` characters do not appear literally within your data and it does also not contain any `?` marks, you could use the following code snippet:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "INFILE=file\workstation"
set "OUTFILE=file\tmp_workstation"
set "SEPARATOR=;"
set /A "COL_NUM=4"
set "COL_NEWVAL=new_value"

rem // A single redirection:
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    set "HEADER=#"
    rem // Read CSV file line by line:
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        if defined HEADER (
            rem // Skip header from replacement:
            set "NEW_LINE=%%L"
            set "HEADER="
        ) else (
            set "NEW_LINE=" & set "SEP=" & set /A "IDX=0"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose any `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
            rem // Use standard `for` loop to enumerate column values:
            for %%I in ("!LINE:%SEPARATOR%=","!") do (
                endlocal
                set /A "IDX+=1"
                set "ITEM=%%~I"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Replace column value if index matches:
                if !IDX! EQU %COL_NUM% (
                    endlocal
                    set "ITEM=%COL_NEWVAL%"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                ) else (
                    if defined ITEM set "ITEM=!ITEM:""="!^"
                )
                rem /* Collect line string;
                rem    `for /F` loop to pass string beyond `endlocal` barrier: */
                for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%E in ("!NEW_LINE!!SEP!!ITEM!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "NEW_LINE=%%E"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
                endlocal
                set "SEP=%SEPARATOR%"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
            endlocal
        )
        rem // Output newly built line:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!NEW_LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Nice, but overkill. A simple `set "line="!line:;=";"!""` and the `FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%1 in ("!line!")`should be enough for a secure splitting

Comment: @jeb, `for /F` does not care about whether a delimiter `;` appears within a quoted field in the CSV data in which case it should not be treated as separator; since the OP does not show how the data looks exactly, I chose the safe way...

Comment: The quotes are not for detecting the delimiters, but to ensure that empty fields will be handeld correct. `a;;c;d` will be converted to `"a";"";"c";"d"` so you can use `FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%1 in ("!line!") DO echo %%~1 _ %%~2 _ %%~3 _ %%~4`, else the second (empty) field would be removed and `%%~2` contains `c` instead of nothing

Comment: I know, @jeb, but (in addition to that) I was thinking of CSV data like `first field;"second;field";third field`, where the second field would be split into two by `for /F`; that is why I chose the complicated way of using standard `for` to split the line (with original quotes doubled intermittently, then quoting each field to avoid adjacent separators, and finally reverting the doubling of quotes)...